# SPFx Creating custom sectionlayout

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to create a modern UI section layout?
e.g. a tab layout

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? Below answers doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Pivot component on Fabric UI

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/pivot

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery UI in SPFx, so you could use jQuery Tabs.

Sample about use jQuery UI.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part