# Custom section layout using SPFX

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to add a custom section layout using SPFX?

I'd like to build a custom layout with my own logic and rules. In the documentation, only Webparts are explained.

My question is similar to [SPFx Creating custom sectionlayout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230110/spfx-creating-custom-sectionlayout) but my requirements is to add WebParts within my custom layout.

[image: OOB sections]

As an alternative, is it possible to build a WebPart that can contains other WebParts ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that SPFx will allow customization/additions to these options since it is outlined as a tool for building webparts, extensions, and add-ins.